# Quicklook crashes on tapping export button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

Upon tapping on button marked application crashes only in iOS 7 with below message ..

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString rangeOfString:options:range:locale:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:
```

How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: can you please see what is the login behind button click ?

Comment: Its a framework.. We wont be able to see the implementation...

Comment: how to did you add that button ?

Comment: ohkey. so you want to share something ?

Comment: I dont want to share anything.. But i dont want my app crash..

Comment: @Uma It comes by default. With QLPreviewController

Comment: you don't want to right bar button items [share button]

Comment: either i want functionality or should not crash... :(